# Gracefully Terminate Console App Run Via Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-file, console, task-scheduler

I'm running a console application on Windows Server 2008. I want it to always run, so I have scheduled it to run at startup via the Task Scheduler.  I set up the task so it does not require a login.

Now how to stop it?  Task Scheduler has an End Task button under All Running Tasks.  But that will abruptly stop the task, which I don't want to do.  I have programmed it so that CTRL-C will issue a stop request, and it will stop when it's done what it's doing.  (For any .NET devs out there I use Console.CancelKeyPress event.)

Is there any way to trigger a cancel key press event (i.e. CTRL-C) in my app when it was run from the Task Scheduler?

(I know one answer is to make it a Windows Service, which I will do eventually, but I need a short term solution.)

Answer (score 0):

In the interim you could make it a service using the [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) utility. it is extremely quick and easy to do. I have found that when the service is stopped, srvany will send a ctrl-c to a console application.

1. Make a service with srvany and sc:

   sc create myservice binpath= "c:\path to\srvany.exe"
2. open regedit and find your service at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
3. right click and add a key called Parameters
4. Create a string value called Application and set it with the path to your console app.

That's it.

I don't know if srvany works with 2008 (my googling suggests it does)I have found that, but I know it works fine on 2003. You can get it from the [Windows 2003 resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).

All you need to do is make scheduled tasks to start and stop the service.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion.  I might try this, but I will probably just make it a service programmatically.  For .NET programmers there's an open source component called TopShelf that makes is really easy to make a console program into a service.